# What is best way to check performance of DAO call (SQL call) using visual studio?

Tags: sql, .net, performance, visual-studio, dao

What is best way to check performance of DAO call (SQL call) using visual studio ?

I am trying to achieve below point:

1. Check each backend call (DAO) execution time?
2. Use this data for performance tuning ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Visual Studio profiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) is a good place to start. It will show you call stacks with inclusive and exclusive times from your .NET code.

If your looking to tune SQL queries however, you'll end up wanting to use SQL Server Management Studio. Taking some time to understand [query plans](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/) and how to read them will benefit you greatly when attempting to improve SQL performance. Management Studio provides the tools to gather and analyze this information.